# Why use a void pointer for dereferencing variables of datatypes?

Tags: c, types, type-conversion, void-pointers

**Dereferencing a float variable using a void pointer:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float a = 7.5;
    void *vp = &a;
    printf("%f", *(float*)vp); /* Typecasting a void pointer to float for dereference */
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output: `7.500000`

**Dereferencing a variable using an integer pointer:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float a = 7.5;
    int *ip = &a;
    printf("%f", *(float*)ip); /* Typecasting an int pointer to float for dereference */
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output: `7.500000`

In both, the outputs are same. What is the reason to go for dereferencing of different datatype variable, when we are able to do by typecasting a normal pointer?

Comment: With `int *ip=&a;` you break *strict aliasing*. You say that `ip` is a pointer to something, but it's really a pointer to something different. A generic pointer using `void *` have no type, it's just a "pointer to something, no matter what it is".

Comment: `void main` must be `int main`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That code would only break strict aliasing if `ip` would be dereferenced. `ip` is cast back to `float*` so code has only implementation defined pointer conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `void` pointer is a ***generic pointer*** which can hold the address of any type and can be ***typecast*** to any type.

In the first case, the program successfully compiled and ran without any warning or error, because using a `void` pointer to convert from one pointer type to another and then storing or casting it to the final type is safe without losing data.

But in the second case the GCC compiler generated a warning

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:5:9: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 int *ip=&a;
     ^
```

**clang compiler:**

```
warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'float *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
int *ip=&a;
     ^  ~~
```

**The C11 Standard, 6.3.2.3, paragraph 7:**

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a
>   pointer to a different object or **incomplete type**. If the resulting
>   pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior
>   is **undefined**.

Answer (score 14):

Converting any data pointer to `void*` pointer and back is guaranteed to give back original pointer.

From C11 standard draft N1570:

> #### 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> 1. A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>      any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall
>      compare equal to the original pointer.

Converting data pointer to other data pointer than `void*` (`int*` in your example) *may* work. It depends on the compiler you are using and the system you are on. Not all systems might use same internal representation for different pointer types.

> 7. **A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
>      resulting pointer is not correctly aligned <sup>68)</sup> for the referenced type, the behavior is
>      undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
>      original pointer.** When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
>      the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the
>      result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

---

This is different from *strict aliasing rules*.

```
float a = 7.5;    
int *ip=&a;
int i = *ip; // Dereferenced using invalid type
```

Code above breaks strict aliasing rule as dereferenced type is not the same as the original type. This results in *undefined behaviour* and is always invalid code.

Comment: Example: say your platform has a strict alignment requirement for floats but not for ints. An int pointer could therefore be represented as its byte offset in memory, but a float pointer might be represented as its *index* in memory because the hypothetical FPU is more efficient loading values that way. On such a system, converting `float*` to `void*` would multiply the underlying address representation by `sizeof(float)` to get a byte offset, but converting `int*` to `void*` is a no-op. Converting directly between `int*` and `float*` would risk UB (6.3.2.3); via `int` would create garbage.

Answer (score 4):

A `void` pointer is (sort of) untyped. It can point to anything without the compiler complaining. e.g. If you have an `int` variable, you can safely create a `void` pointer that points to this and pass it around. e.g.

```
int x = 10;
void *p = &x
```

is fine but

```
int x = 10;
float *p = &x;
```

will upset the compiler

This is especially useful for functions that operate on multiple pointer types or if you will decide what something is at runtime.

However, void pointers cannot be dereferenced (`*`) directly because the compiler doesn't know their type. So,

```
printf("%d\n", *p);
```

will break if p is void pointer. We have to know the size of what it points to to dereference it and this is done using a manual type cast (like what you've done).

In your specific case, you have a pointer that points to a float which you type cast back into float before printing it. So, you will get the same output. The `void *` pointer is not really playing a big role here.

An example of where you need a `void *` is the `malloc` function, If you look at the prototype, it returns a `void *`. i.e. a block of raw memory. You need to typecast this as a concrete type before you can do pointer arithmetic and dereferencing.

Comment: "We have to know the size". No, we have to know the type. Size is not sufficient.

Comment: True. Although, I'm not exactly sure about why we'd need to know that. If you can elaborate, I'm sure it'd be useful.